# Output Uri from this Android crop image library?

Tags: android, image, uri, crop

I'm trying to implement [SoundCloud's image crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) to my app. Here's what I'm doing so far:

call `Crop.pickImage((Activity) this)` to pick an image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri inputUri = data.getData();
        new Crop(inputUri).output(outputUri).asSquare().start((Activity) context);
    }
    else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri cropped = data.getData();
    }
}
```

At this point I don't know what should be the `outputUri`. I can just use the same `inputUri` as the output, but that would overwrite the original image file. I want to create a new file instead. But I can't create new Uri since Android Studio tells me the newly initialized Uri is abstract and can't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following methods for my cropping image library for URI creation as well. Hopefully it will helps you:

```
private void fileSaving(){
        String stateEnvironment = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(stateEnvironment)) {
            mFileTemp = ChatUtils.getOutputMediaFile(101);//new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        } else {
            mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir(), sTEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        }
    }

    private void takePicture() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        try {
            Uri mImageCaptureUri = null;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);
            } else {
                // mImageCaptureUri =
                // InternalStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
            }
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mImageCaptureUri);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, mREQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
```